# The rational numbers are totally disconnected but not a discrete space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Any set of the form $\{x, y\}$ is disconnected.  Wouldn't this imply that the rational numbers is a discrete space, since $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$ are open?

Comment: $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$ are only open relative to $\{x,y\}$ but not in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: (nor in $\mathbb Q$)

Answer (score 4):

An open set of the subspace topology on $\Bbb Q$ is obtained by taking the intersection  of $\Bbb Q$ with an open set of $\Bbb R$. Any non-empty open set in $\Bbb R$ contains an interval. So, could   $\{x\}$ possibly be open in $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Isn't {x} open in the subspace topology on {x, y}?

Comment: Yes, but is $\{x,y\}$ open in $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @Mike $\{x\}$ is open in the space $\{x,y\}$.  But singleton sets are not open in $\Bbb Q$. This is so because you cannot write $\{x\}=O\cap  \Bbb Q$ with $O$ an  open set of $\Bbb R$ (a non-empty open subset of $\Bbb R$ contains infinitely many rationals).

Comment: Okay thanks.   I forgot that a subset of a space being connected/disconnected means being connected/disconnected in its subspace topology.

Comment: @Mike $\{x\}$ is open in $\{x\}$ but that doesn't mean that $\{x\}$ is open in $\mathbb R$ or that $\mathbb R$ is discrete.